# the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying this code :

```
string file =@"C:\Program.xml";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(XElement.Load(file));
XElement root = XElement.Parse(doc);
```

I get the following error :

```
the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments
```

I really need some help...I've been searchig for some hours for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XElement.Parse(string s)` or `XElement.Parse(string s, LoadOptions l)` hasn't a overload that accept an `XDocument` control.
According to [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement) dotnetperls' example you can do this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("myFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

`XElement.Parse` is used to load xml from a string, whereas `Load` is used to load an xml file - generally you won't need to use both.

I think you may be looking to do something like:

```
string file = @"C:\Program.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XElement root = doc.Root;
var value = root.Element("foo").Attribute("bar");
```